# Angular JS chart

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I want to develop a simple Angular JS Chart.

Like the one in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T9J7bz?p=preview).

But, I need to make this `chart compatible to IE 8`. I viewed this on Mozilla and chrome but it is not visible in IE 8. Can anyone please please help me with this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try highCharts. See this Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9YnpS/29/

Answer (score -1):

Use [Pablojim's Angular Highchart](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) implementation. Works in IE8